# censor last 4 letters of email

Tags: regex, email, replace, sublimetext

I want to search & replace a list of email and censor the last 4 letters of them.
What regex should I use?

eg:
FROM

`abcd123@hotmail.com
9920ds11@gmail.com`

TO

`abcxxxx@hotmail.com
9920xxxx@gmail.com`

Comment: What will the output when the email is less than 4 characters `Eg: abc@hotmail.com`

Answer (score 1):

This pattern should work:

**[search]**

```
.{1,4}(?=\@.*?)
```

**[replace]**

```
xxxx
```

- note any email address prefix <= 4 will simply be `xxxx@example.com`

Answer (score 0):

I just noticed that you are using Sublime Text. You can easily do:

- **Find**: `(.*)(....)(@.*)`
- **Replace**: `$1xxxx$3`

Note: It will only replace the emails that have at least 4 characters and leave others untouched.

---

<s>In `C++11`, you can use:</s>

```
if (s.substr(0, s.find('@')).size() >= 4) // only handle email with >= 4 chars
{
    const regex r("(.*)(....)(@.*)");  
    const string fmt("$1xxxx$3");  

    string res = regex_replace(s, r, fmt);
}
```

See it live: http://rextester.com/EJV24903

Comment: be careful ! if the email's first part is shorter than 4 character (it happens!) it will be fully visible

Comment: @OlivierDulac Thanks for pointing this out. Updated the answer to mention this.

Answer (score 0):

In `Java`

Regex is `[\w.!#$%&'*+=?^{}|~\/-]{4}(?=@)`

The email accepts character as per http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address

Check here for a demo

http://regex101.com/r/kZ2fE5

CODE:

```
String test = "abcd123@hotmail.com";
test        = test.replace("[\\w.!#$%&'*+=?^`{}|~\\/-]{4}(?=@)","xxxx");
System.out.println(test)
```

When the email is less than 4 characters, no replacement takes place

Comment: regex could be simplified to [\w]{4}(?=@)

Comment: @akfaz: No, it can't be simplified. Email addresses might contain `numbers` also

Comment: Yes You are right, but keep in mind that \w already includes numbers "Matches an alphanumeric character, including "_";
same as [A-Za-z0-9_] in ASCII." http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression

Comment: @KrishnaM, you should also take into account emails with periods, underscores, dashes, etc.